# What does the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI i s not hierarchical" mean?

Tags: java, jar, uri

I have an java application, that is decoding information on a image using an xml file. The xml file is in the top most package. This is the code I am using to get the file

```
java.net.URL url = DecodeButton.class.getResource("/text.xml");
File process_file = new File(url.toURI());
```

The code is working fine when running in eclipse. When I am creating the jar, and pressing the decode button to perform the decoding, this is error:

> jar:file:/C:/simple3.jar!/text.xml Exception in thread
>   "AWT-EventQueue-0 " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not
>   hierarchical
>   at java.io.File.(Unknown Source)
>   at com.simplediptool.DecodeButton1.actionPerformed(DecodeButton1.java:70)

```
   Line 70: File process_file = new File(url.toURI());
```

where I am going wrong?

Comment: You appear to be running this on windows. Try replacing the unix file seperators "/" with the Windows file seperator "\".

Comment: It’s working fine in Eclipse because in Eclipse your classes and resources reside in the native file system. When packed into a jar, the resources are no ordinary files, hence you can’t convert their URL (a `jar:` URL as seen in the exception’s message) into a `File` object— they aren’t files.

Comment: But it that case, it wont even compile in eclipse @DavisBroda

Comment: @Holger: how to resolve it then?

Comment: There is no way to create a `File` object for something that isn’t a file. But that’s an “XY problem”; the question is why you think you need a `File`, in other words, what’s your *actual* problem.

Comment: @Holger: I am trying to create a file object process_file. There are different functions that requires the a file object be passed.

Comment: As said, you don’t have a file. So you have to replace these “different functions that requires the a file object be passed” by functions which do not require `File` objects. There are different abstractions, e.g. `InputStream`, however, as long as you don’t name these functions, we can’t help you finding the appropriate replacements.

Comment: @Holger: Thank you . I have to work with some existing code to do the decoding. They have been created by some other developer and I cannot change it. So that is the constrainst.

Comment: The last resort is to copy the contents of the resource to a temporary file, however, that’s really rarely necessary. Often, the alternatives are simply overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
DecodeButton.class.getResource(......);
```

Use

```
DecodeButton.class.getResourceAsStream(........);
```

JAR file is a united file with many resources inside it, just like a ZIP or WAR file. To access a single resource, you need to treat it as a stream, hence use the above. On the other hand in eclipse, the files can be accessed directly as a resource, hence it works.

This shall solve your problem.

Comment: Using `getResourceAsStream(…)`, which is just a shorthand for `getResource(…).openStream()`, will solve the problem *if* an `InputStream` is desired. At the moment we simply don’t know what the OP wants to do with the file. E.g. if the resource ought to be passed to an XML parser, passing the `URL` directly to the parser is preferred as that tells the parser how to resolve relative links and helps providing better error messages if something goes wrong.

Comment: Holger, you seem to be getting the question wrong. Here the question is the code compiles and runs successfully in eclipse, but after creating a JAR throws the said exception. This clearly states that the resource is not accessible and basic thumb rule is in any JAR file if you want to access a resource, treat it as a stream. It shall definitely work.

Comment: I know exactly what the question is. Is is *not* asking for a “basic thumb rule”. A stream *can* solve the problem, but not in every case. That simply depends on the operation. E.g. you can’t write into the resource that way and you can’t list the siblings of the resource that way.

Comment: @Iqbal: thank you. But I need to create a file object. Using a getResourceAs stream i am getting an inputstream object.

Comment: @javanewbie, just use any of the methods given in the below link to convert the input stream into a file object, it will be done: http://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-a-file

Comment: Just wanted to say that this change suggested by Iqbal S was the solution for me.

Comment: Glad that it helped you @SomeGuy. Upvotes are appreciated. Thanks!